# Formatting a number to two digits even if the first is a 0 vba

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, string-formatting

I would like to be able to use VBA to display any number between 1-24 as a 2 digit number. Obviously the only ones that have a problem with this are 1-9 which I would like displayed as 01, 02, 03, etc. Is there a way to perform this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You cannot format an integer variable, you need to use a string variable for formatting.

You can convert the day part of a date to a format with leading zeros using the `Day` function to extract the day number from the date, and then using the `Format` function with a `"00"` format to add a leading zero where necessary

> Format(Day(myDate), "00")

myDate is a Date variable containing the full Date value

The following macro can be used as a working sample

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim myDate As Date

    myDate = "2015-5-1"

    Dim dayPart  As String

    dayPart = Format(Day(myDate), "00")

    MsgBox dayPart
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to apply this to a number generated in the code not one in a cell will this work the same way? Can I simply change it to MyVar.NumberFormat = "00"

Comment: Well I tried that and I got Run-Time Error '424' Object Required on the line MyVar.NumberFormat = "00"

Comment: If this helps at all the number I am needing to format is the day portion of a date that I have extracted from a the date provided via a userform.

Comment: @ChadPortman I've amended my answer in light of your comments. This should be what you're after.

Comment: You sir are a saint. Thank you

Comment: The OP originally said a *number* and *using VBA*. The number has been extracted from a date in a userform.  strResult = Format(number, "00") works.

Answer (score 7):

Sure you can format an integer, you just convert it to string within the format command:

```
formattedIntAsString = Format(Cstr(intValue), "00")
```

Answer (score 4):

I did it like this:

```
number_item = 2
number_item = WorksheetFunction.Text(number_item, "00")
```

This will do the job.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's old, but, to answer the question as clarified, I would use in the built in date formatting functionality.

To modify DeanOC's answer:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim dateDate As Date
    Dim strDate  As String
    Dim strDay  As String

    dateDate = "2015-5-1"
    strDate = Format(dateDate, "mm/dd/yy") ' = "05/01/15"
    strDay = Format(dateDate, "dd")        ' = "01"

    MsgBox "The two digit day of """ & strDate & """ is """ & strDay & ""."
End Sub
```

Comment: There are other (accepted) answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some years ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Comment: In my opinion, using the built in formatting to extract the day from a date variable in a single step is a new solution.  My approach can better be generalized.  For example, I often use "yymmdd" format, so that the string representation of dates sort well.  Using the approach of the previous responses, I would need to use Format(Year(dateDate),"00") & Format(Month(dateDate),"00") & Format(Day(dateDate),"00"). With my approach, I can use Format(dateDate,"yymmdd") function.  There are many other formatting options for other number types.  I suspect that my approach is faster, too.